# Div not refreshing with AJAX Call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am developing and MVC 5 application.  On a page I have a partial view where I load content from a ECM Repository.  So file name and uploaded date.  This works fine on page load.

My partial view cshtml is something like:

```
<form id="searchForm" class="h-form">
    <div class="form-group row">
     content for cmis search lives here - removed for brevity
    </div>
</form>

<div class="table-responsive top-margin">
    <table id="myFiles" class="table table-striped table-hover"></table>
</div>
```

When loading the page I have a javascript search function that is called.

```
function mySearch() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'mysearchurl',
        type: 'GET',
        data: $('#searchForm').serialize(),
        success: function (data) { buildFileList(data); },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status + " " + thrownError); }
    });
    return false;
}
```

My buildFileList function then is as below (Note myFiles is the Div on the partial view where the results are displayed.:

```
function buildFileList(data) {
    $('#myFiles').empty();
    $('#myFiles').append('<thead><tr><th>File Name</th><th>Uploaded Date</th></tr></thead><tbody>');
    $.each(data.results, function (index, value) {
        $('#myFiles').append("Data built up for each file");
    });
 }
```

I have an upload files ajax function which uploads a file to the ECM.  In the success function of this ajax method I then call the search(); function again but the myFiles Div is not getting updated with the new file that was uploaded even though the upload was successful.  I then changed and moved the call to the search() function to the complete function of the ajax method but the myFiles Div is not getting refreshed with the new content.  However if I refresh the page where the search(); fucntion is also called on document.ready the myFiles div is updated with the new files that were added.

Comment: I used setTimeout(search,5000); in my success function - sometimes it os working and uploading the content in the table and other times it doesnt seem to run and doesnt update the table... :/

Comment: What's in the 'data' value if you put a breakpoint in buildFileList? It would be interesting to see what you get if you debug. What is your controller method like? Do you get any ajax errors?